# django: part of javascript translation doesnot work

Tags: javascript, django, internationalization, gettext

here is my code:

```
 var text = `<div id='weather_data'>
            <img id='weather_icon' src='${weather_icon}'>
            <span id='centered'>${data[0].temperature}°c</span>
            </div>
            <h2>Steps:</h2>
            <ul id='journey_info'>`;
```

and

```
 text +=
                "<li>" +
                gettext(" Start from: ") +
                "<br>" +
                data[i].start_name +
                "<br>" +
                "<br>" +
                gettext(" Line ID: ") +
                line_id +
                "<br>" +
                "<br>" +
                gettext(" Departs at: ") +
                getTime(data, i) +
                `<div id='arrival_${stop_id}'></div>` +
                "<br>" +
                gettext(" Arrives to: ") +
                "<br>" +
                data[i].end_name +
                "<br>" +
                "<br>" +
                gettext(" Stops: ") +
                data[i].num_stops +
                " • " +
                data[i].travel_time +
                "mins <span id='arrow'>&#9660</span>" +
                "<div id='directions_stops_list'>";
```

in my *djangojs.po* file,
there are only :

```
#: .\static\javascript\modals.js:49
msgid " Arrives to: "
msgstr " 到达："

#: .\static\javascript\modals.js:54
msgid " Stops: "
msgstr "站点："
```

so part of gettext are found by django.
but Why can't it read: gettext(" Start from: "),gettext(" Line ID: ") and gettext(" Departs at: ")?

**Notice:** any code between `var text =` and  `` `<div id='arrival_${stop_id}'></div>` + `` couldnot be recognized by **gettext**.

Comment: Move "Arrives to" up, rerun `python manage.py makemessages --locale cn` till it doesn't show up anymore. That should provide a hint.

Comment: code before ``` `<div id='arrival_${stop_id}'></div>` + ``` couldnot work. but I donnot know how to solve this

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much. Are you sure the syntax is correct everywhere? Do you have a stray backtick or single quote lying around?

Comment: I stuck the part that you are showing in a file and ran `python manage.py makemessages --domain djangojs --locale cn --ignore 'node_modules'` and it is correct, so the problem is elsewhere in the file.

Comment: Hey I have edited my question again. I think it is because of the template string. but I donot know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but it all works for me:

```
#: templates/modal.js:9
msgid " Start from: "
msgstr ""

#: templates/modal.js:14
msgid " Line ID: "
msgstr ""

#: templates/modal.js:18
msgid " Departs at: "
msgstr ""

#: templates/modal.js:22
msgid " Arrives to: "
msgstr ""

#: templates/modal.js:27
msgid " Stops: "
msgstr ""
```

But since we're missing ~27 lines, you should simply delete one statement at a time from the top, till it starts working. There's something that Django trips over and until you identify it, there's not much we can do to help.